# How do I segment my network?

Tags: vlan, firewall, subnet, pfsense

I'm on a network where I don't own the router and I don't want to modify the network existing network by running a firewall over the entire network however I want to have a firewall protecting my server. How would I go about segmenting my network? I want to use a hardware firewall, probably in a pfSense box, I've been reading about subnets and VLANs, is there a way I could use these to split up my network into a separate many network that just my computer and server would be on?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pfsense will bridge. Seems to me the easiest route would be to isolate the two machines behind your pfsense box and bridge the outside interface with the inside. No reconfig of IP yet you have the separation you desire. You could even do some port forwarding if you wanted access to your server from the outside LAN.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to want access from outside my lan so that will be important. When you say bridge the outside interface through the pfSense box, do you mean hook the network up to the pfSense box and then the pfSense box to a switch which I can connect to my computer and server?

Comment: Yes to your question -- connect pfsense WAN interface to your exising LAN then connect pfsense LAN interface to a new swtich, then connect computer and server to new switch. After that configure a bridge in pfsense and add both LAN and WAN interfaces.